# Provide free tag icons for non-profit projects

Tags: feature-request, sponsored-tags

It is possible to add icons to tags as part of promotions. However, several tags exist that would benefit of an icon but without any likely sponsor (E.g. open standards, some programming languages, and several open-source projects)

Stack Exchange sites would look more interesting if such tags had icons, and possibly that would also make potential sponsors more interested in sponsoring tag icons.

Comment: FWIW, there is (sort of) a precedent with [the Prior Art Request tag on Ask Patents](https://patents.meta.stackexchange.com/q/353/17737).